# Join with null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables Parent and child table, child table contains foreign key constraint.

Now I want to get data from child table with join to parent table and also want the records where parent table id is null from child table.

Answer (score 1):

```
   select *
     from child c
left join parent p on c.id = c.parent_id;
```